TvContract.PreviewPrograms doesnt retrieve specific programs
I wanted to ask about TvContract.PreviewPrograms for Android. Since I have a TV application to show featured content on the home screen but for some reason I can't show featured content from Max (ex HBO) but it does come to me from Pluto.tv, Amazon, etc. Could it be that MAx has no content? or is it a bug in my App? either by the query or by the TV provider?
I am trying to show the highlights for Max on the home screen but the query brings me programs from other apps that I have installed but not Max's (which is also installed)
